# Java - merge sort using linked list pointers

Tags: java, sorting

I'm having issues implementing a merge sort for a linked list, specifically, the merge part. I'm trying to sort a linked list containing strings and sort them alphabetically. However, my merge code sometimes skips pointers for some reason depending on the order of the original list. Currently I have:

```
public node merge(node left, node right){
        node result = null;

        if(left == null){
            return right;
        }else if(right == null){
            return left;
        }   

        // The data in the node are stored as strings.
        // Compare if the string in the left node is less that 
        // the string in the right.
        if(left.info.compareTo(right.info) < 0){
            result = left;
            result.next = merge(left.next, right);
        }else{
            result = right;
            result.next = merge(left, right.next);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

If I had a list that consisted of for example, f->t->c->t->h, my merge will return h->t->t, where pointers are being missed. However, if my list consisted of b->a->t->t->c then it correctly display it alphabetically, a->b->c->t->t, and no pointers are missed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why would you not wanna post your split function.. it will definitely help ustand the question better..

Comment: merge logic looks fine.. please post the split function

Comment: Any reason why you don't use Java's own `LinkedList` and `Collections.sort(list)` to perform that merge sort?

Comment: a challenge or an homework probably.. how does that matter? its like giving a jquery soln/why not use jquery to any javascript dom manipulation question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you are holding the old pointers to left and right which may no longer be the heads to the sub-lists.

Change

```
 mergeSort(left);
 mergeSort(right);
```

to

```
 left = mergeSort(left);
 right = mergeSort(right);
```

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it. I just tested it against lists containing one node, two nodes, odd/even number of nodes, and everything seems to work perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't worth an answer, but here it is.

It's a bit hard to figure out what's going on there, I for one didn't notice any glaring mistakes in the implementation (although I wouldn't use recursion on the merge part, it's simpler to implement it "iteratively").

In my opinion, you need to figure out what's going on step by step. If you know a couple of examples that work and that don't work (seems like you do), call each method directly with the expected input.

For instance, to figure out for sure if your split is working, create a list and pass it to split, print the result. Then call split on the two lists created by split, and so on, to make sure what's happening. (Now would be a good time to use JUnit, but you can do that by "hand" if you want to).

If split works fine for the several cases you can think of, then call the merge routine with two lists, and analyze the result in the same fashion. If that works ok, then add some debugging output to your merge.

Basically, test each part of your algorithm independently, it'll me a lot faster to figure out the problem then looking at it as a whole.

Sorry for writing up a wall of text and still not answering the question, but this is how I would try to solve the problem.

Comment: Unit tests RULE! Totally agree on using JUnit to help narrow scope of analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just a quick question though - is there any difference in implementing the merge part iteratively rather than recursively besides being simpler? Time/space complexity perhaps?

Comment: Yes and no... the complexity will stay the same, but for very large lists, you'll be creating a huge stack of recursive calls, and there's a limit for that. Basically for each non-terminal recursive call, the JVM needs to add another context entry to the stack, when the recusive calls stop, they'll start getting solved until your method finally returns.